# ServerClickHandler results in "Error encountered: Required: required"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

There seems to be a problem in my ServerClickHandler in my Google Apps Script.
When running my App and submitting the button the error message is "Error encountered: Required: required"
Does anyone know why this happens?

```
var User = new Object(),
Url  = new Object();
// Startet die Web-App
function doGet() {
  User.email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();//Create a panel which will hold all the elements
  var longUrlLabel = app.createLabel( 'lange E-Mail hier eingeben - Kurzlink wird dann per E-Mail zugesendet' );
  var longUrlBox = app.createTextBox().setName( 'longUrl' )
                                    .setText( 'http://www.' );
  var longUrlLabelInfo = app.createLabel().setId( 'shortUrlLabelInfo' ).setVisible( false );
  var button = app.createButton( 'Ausführen' );


  var handler = app.createServerClickHandler( 'buttonOnClickListener' );
  //createHandler for the Button-onClick-Event.
  handler.addCallbackElement( panel );
  button.addClickHandler( handler ); //Add this handler to the button 

  //Add all the UI elements to the panel
  panel.add( longUrlLabel )
       .add( longUrlBox )
       .add( button );
  app.add( panel );//Add the panel to the application
  return app;
}

function buttonOnClickListener( eventInfo ) {
  var app;
  Url.long  = eventInfo.parameter.longUrl.toString();
  Url.short = UrlShortener.Url.insert( UrlShortener.newUrl().setLongUrl( Url.short ) );
  sendMail();
  app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById( 'longUrlLabelInfo' ).setVisible(true).setText( Url.short );

  return app; 
}

function sendMail() {
  GmailApp.sendEmail( User.email, "UrlShortener", Url.long+" -> "+Url.short );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this : (EDIT : I did improve the UI a little and the email layout to get a more clear and readable value + translate in English ;-) sorry about that but my german is very poor.(;-)

```
var User = new Object(),
Url  = new Object();
User.email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setStyleAttributes({'padding':'40px','backgroundColor':'#fafacc'});
  var longUrlLabel = app.createLabel( 'Enter the long url starting with http:// you will receive an email with the short url immediately.' );
  var longUrlBox = app.createTextBox().setName( 'longUrl' ).addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forEventSource().setText(''))
  .setText( 'http://' ).setWidth('500');
  var shortUrlLabel = app.createHTML().setId( 'shortUrlLabel' ).setVisible( false );


  var handler = app.createServerHandler( 'buttonOnClickListener' ).addCallbackElement( panel );
  var button = app.createButton( 'SUBMIT',handler ).setStyleAttributes({'border-radius':'5px'});

  var grid = app.createGrid(8,1).setId('grid')
  .setWidget(0,0,longUrlLabel )
  .setWidget(2,0,longUrlBox )
  .setWidget(4,0,button )
  .setWidget(6,0,shortUrlLabel);

  return app.add( panel.add(grid));
}

function buttonOnClickListener( eventInfo ) {
  var app =UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var toShorten = UrlShortener.newUrl().setLongUrl(eventInfo.parameter.longUrl);
  var shortened = UrlShortener.Url.insert(toShorten);
  Url.short = UrlShortener.Url.insert(toShorten);
  Url.long = eventInfo.parameter.longUrl;
  sendMail();
  app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById( 'shortUrlLabel' ).setVisible(true).setHTML('<li>Short url = <b>'+Url.short.id+'</b></li><li>Mail sent ...</li>');
  app.getElementById('grid').setWidget(7,0,app.createAnchor('test (with redirect warning)', Url.short.id));

  return app; 
}

function sendMail() {
  GmailApp.sendEmail( User.email, "UrlShortener", 'Long url (original) = '+Url.long+"\n\n\nShort url = "+Url.short.id);
}
```

[image]

Comment: User.email is not initialized in the click handler. Globals only live during each callback not in betweeen so init them outside doget

Comment: works, thank you! :)

*Edit*
Problem: Not the User who is using the app receive the E-Mail but allways me. So
    GmailApp.sendEmail( User.email,
Allways go to the E-Mail of the Script-Admin (me) :( I don't understand because I set the correct settings when publishing the app.

Comment: Thank you, was an interesting function :-) please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: It works for me, my other account received the email, feel free to test  with this link :http://goo.gl/WU1ibr  (this is a shortened one  ;-))

Comment: Why does it works in your script that the active user receives the email? 
GmailApp.sendEmail( User.email,...); sends the email allways to me but in the header-information stands the correct target-email ...

Comment: Have you tried on more than one account?  Could you post the app link here so I can test it too?

Comment: yes I dit. 
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw6NrvabRgVCYiaDc6UU7ke0o8g5YHU-VJf72X0VBRdkX_CfYtG/exec

Comment: working ! I received the email :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script -> http://goo.gl/3ZsJ50  as expected...

Comment: Hahah I am stupid! xD I am sorry, my mistake. My second account redirect all mails to my main account .. XD I am sorry. ;)

Comment: ;-) I suspected something like that but didn't dare to say  XD so, happy end !!